# HOw many ESP partition?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi

My disk is in use of UEFI table, only one only 44 MB ESP partition is needed because I only have one OS. If I want more OS installed, how many ESP partition I would prepare for the multiple OSes?

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one ESP that is shared between the operating systems.If you have more than one hard disk, I still recommend only one ESP total, because otherwise you will have to go into the firmware setup to choose which hard disk boot from.

You can use a chooser program like the rEFInd boot manager, or Grub, to present a menu from which the user can choose which OS to start.